# Line-continued blocks of text

Tags: html, css

I have one paragraph of text broken into 4 parts. Each part should be highlighted with its own color, including space at the end of each line and space between lines, all the way to the next part. For example:

[image]

Is it possible with only HTML and CSS? No JS and SVG please.

*Also, can you suggest a better title for this question?*

**Update:** Text should be aligned left.

Comment: Are you asking for this to happen automatically, or with inline style per part?

Comment: @Daniel Automatically. I don't know how many lines each block of text will produce. The width of the outer container is not fixed and text blocks should adjust accordingly if container is resized.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a combination of `<p>` tags inside a block elemnt. While on the css you'll need to justify your text and apply backgrounds to each element.

Hope this helps :)

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
    background: pink;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}


p:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque  </p>
<p>laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab  </p>
<p>illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </p>
<p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, with `text-align: justify` it works but I should have added to my question that the text should be left aligned, like on the picture. Anyway, thanks for the right direction.

Comment: Ur welcome and thanks for the upvote. Ill see if i can whip something with leftalign :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using spans

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, ab repellat eveniet fuga cumque ipsum rerum quam, porro enim nihil in odio dolore dignissimos ipsam laudantium temporibus necessitatibus, ratione distinctio.</span>
  <span
    class="yellow">Quidem id sit, facilis hic maiores, sed fuga consequuntur eveniet nobis magnam praesentium optio reiciendis nesciunt ratione quasi, voluptas, ut iusto exercitationem. Deserunt error voluptate, veniam debitis ex explicabo animi.</span><span class="green">Facere quae odit sunt obcaecati itaque voluptatem esse! Repellendus nesciunt fugit ullam esse, similique ducimus quis distinctio saepe, modi. Repudiandae, id tempora explicabo. Perspiciatis, molestiae, repudiandae. Excepturi placeat doloribus, dignissimos.</span>
    <span
      class="lightblue">Nesciunt saepe possimus, autem molestias repellat maiores quasi ex sit eveniet cupiditate ducimus voluptatibus ipsam necessitatibus, sed fuga impedit aspernatur corporis deleniti optio quaerat! Quaerat quia ipsa voluptatum cumque qui.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The end of each continued line should have the same background as under text. With simple spans end of the lines has white background.

Comment: Try using text-align: justify

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  font-size: 0; /* prevents whitespace between spans to ruin the result */
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 22px; /* reset to the font-size needed here */
  line-height: 1; /* prevents white lines between the text blocks */
}

span+span {
  background: cyan;
}

span+span+span {
  background: lime;
}

span+span+span+span {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>I have one paragraph of text broken into 4 parts. Each part should be highlighted with its own color, including space at the end of each line and space between lines, all the way to the next part. For example:</span>
  <span>Is it possible with only HTML and CSS? No JS and SVG please.

Also, can you suggest a better title for this question?</span>
  <span>I have one paragraph of text broken into 4 parts. Each part should be highlighted with its own color, including space at the end of each line and space between lines, all the way to the next part. For example:</span>
  <span>Is it possible with only HTML and CSS? No JS and SVG please.

Also, can you suggest a better title for this question?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: At the end of each line you have white background. It should be the same background color to the edge of the outer block. That's the main problem in my question. Otherwise I would not ask it :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, nah, that won't be achievable. The only thing you can do is set `text-align: justify;` on the parent, but that a) creates tiny white line between sections and b) is not what your desired result looks like.